# Wasserstein distance between Gaussian and the empirical distribution

Tags: distribution, gaussian

Wasserstein distance between two gaussians has a closed form solution. Does the same hold for the distance between a Gaussian with a fixed variance(say 1) and the empirical data distribution?

Empirical data distibution defined as:
$$ p(x) = \frac{\sum_i \delta (x - x_i)}{n} $$

And the 1-d Gaussian with $\sigma^2 = 1$ and some unknown mean $\mu$
$$ q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Comment: describing a probability distribution with Diracs is far too general to call it an empirical distribution. maybe just be direct and tell us what the empirical data really is and its statistical properties